# check two slashes in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have following sting. I wanted to know any string has two slashes or not.

```
      $sting = "largeimg/fee0b04800e22590/myimage1.jpg";
```

I am trying to use the following PHP emthodl

```
     if(preg_match("@^/([A-Za-z]|[0-9])/([A-Za-z]|[0-9]+)$@", $sting))
```

But it is not working properly. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it in regex (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eS1gA6)):

```
^([^/]*/){2}
```

Your code:

```
if(preg_match("@^([^/]*/){2}@", $sting)) {
// two slashes!
}
```

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
(                        # group and capture to \1 (2 times):
  [^/]*                  #   any character except: '/' (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
  /                      #   '/'
){2}                     # end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                         # quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                         # repetition of the captured pattern will be
                         # stored in \1)
```

Comment: +1 - Question: Did you use a tool to auto-generate the commented version or did you write it by hand?

Comment: @ridgerunner Always good to hear from you. For speed (simple regex) I used [explain1](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) or [explain2](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl) and added formatting. Both come from YAPE::Regexp::Explain that is a bit messy. For complex regexps I usually explain by hand. One danger of automatic online tools is that they target one particular flavor, so `\d means digits 0 to 9` will be wrong in .NET for instance (unicode digits). If you want something automatic and correct in cases like that, RegexBuddy lets you copy its token-by-token tree explanation.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I ask is because I'm about to release just such a tool: [RegexTidy](http://regextidy.org). I was pretty sure that no such tool exists yet so your answer scared me a bit!

Comment: @ridgerunner Don't worry, there is nothing really general out there. I'm really excited to see your too and have bookmarked it. :) You're probably aware that you can also grab explanations on sites such as [regex101](http://regex101.com/). Apart from the multi-flavor dimension, one thing missing from such tools is often a natural, casual language, which is why I and other people here like Explain and variations thereof. I started tweaking it on my machine but ran out of time. `(?R)` and such are missing. Long live RegexTidy! :)

Comment: For a preview, you may want to check out my [Dynamic Regex Syntax Highlighter](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighter.html) project - RegexTidy uses a similar methodology for parsing nested groups using javascript regex. It recognizes (and provides comments for) all PCRE 8.x group types (e.g.`(?R)`, `(?DEFINE..)`, `(?(1)..)`, etc.) and includes built-in dynamic syntax highlighting. It will also be released as open source. You heard it here first!

Comment: @ridgerunner Wow... that is very promising indeed! That must be a hugely complex parser to write and maintain, as Philip Hazel & al. never sit still. On the list from 2010 I don't see `(*SKIP)` and `(*F)` on the list, but I imagine you'll have them in the parser? More and more of us seem to be using it. Mind you, it's not in RegexBuddy yet. :) Thanks very much for the advance notice, thrilled to hear about it.

Comment: Hey purab, Did this solve your problem? Btw, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an answer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). You can also upvote answers (up arrow on the left) that you accept and other answers you like. Of course there is no obligation to do so. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tut. :) Have a nice week-end!

Answer (score 3):

you could use [substr_count()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.substr-count.php), do:

```
$sting = "largeimg/fee0b04800e22590/myimage1.jpg";
if(substr_count($sting, '/') == 2) { echo "has 2 slashes"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for 2 slashes you can use this regex:

```
preg_match('@/[^/]*/@', $sting)
```

Answer (score 1):

Several other answers provide regular expressions that work but they do not explain why the expression in the question does not work. The expression is:

```
@^/([A-Za-z]|[0-9])/([A-Za-z]|[0-9]+)$@
```

The section `([A-Za-z]|[0-9])` is equivalent to `([A-Za-z0-9])`. The extra `+` in the second similar section makes that part quite different. The `+` is of higher precedence than the `|`. Hence the section `([A-Za-z]|[0-9]+)` is equivalent to `([A-Za-z]|([0-9]+))` (ignoring the difference between capturing and non-capturing brackets). The expression is interpreted as:

```
^                 Start of string
/                 The character '/'
([A-Za-z]|[0-9])  One alphanumeric
/                 The character '/'
(                 
    [A-Za-z]      One alpha character
    |             or
    [0-9]+        One or more digits
)                 
$                 End of the string
```

This will only match strings where the first three characters are `/`, one alphanumeric, then `/`. Then the remainder of the string must be either one alpha or several digits. Thus these strings would be matched:

```
/a/b
/c/123
/4/d
/5/6
/7/890123456789
```

These strings would not be matched:

```
/aa/b
c/c/123
/44/d
/5/6a
/5/a6
/7/ee
```